# Handling of notification/error messages with regards to the browser's Back button

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, webforms, form-submit

On our ASP.NET/C# web application, we are handling error/notifications with a `div` in our Master page that is set to `Visible="false"`.  What we are doing is, from our aspx pages when we want to create a notification message using the following code:

```
public static void DisplayNotificationMessage(MasterPage Master, string message)
{
    if (Master.FindControl("divmsgpanel") != null)
    {
        Master.FindControl("divmsgpanel").Visible = true;
    }

    TextBox thetxtbox = (TextBox)Master.FindControl("txtboxmsgcontents");

    if (thetxtbox != null)
    {
        thetxtbox.Text = message;
    }
}
```

And the HTML in the Master page:

```
<%--start msgpanel--%>
<div id="divmsgpanel" runat="server" visible="false">
<div id="msgpanelheader">
</div>
<div id="divmsgpanelmainstage">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtboxmsgcontents" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
        Width="249px" SkinId="messageboxcontents"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="lblmsgcontents" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>
<div id="msgpanelfooter">
    <asp:Button ID="btnmsgcloser" runat="server" Text="Close" 
        onclick="btnmsgcloser_Click" />
</div>
</div><%--end msgpanel--%>
```

This is working quite well so far --- it offers us a centralized way of handling error messages for all pages, while allowing us to easily style the message box to the style of the overall site.  We can just call this `DisplayNotifcationMessage` method from any page in one line.  The `div` contains a "Close" button as well, which again makes it `Visible="false"`.

The only problem we are having (or at least, the only problem we are aware of, anyway!) is with forms submission.  On our "Add Employees" page, for example, after you have successfully added an employee, you get a nice notification message using the above method, which says "Employee successfully added."  The problem is, is that after you hit the message box's "Close" button, you can press the browsers back button to go Back to the page's previous state (which had the message box's Visible attribute set to true).

I found some guides that detail "tricks" to "disable" the back button (such as [A Thorough Examination of "Disabling The Back Button"](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927201700/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/111500-1.shtml).  Ultimately though, these "tricks" are not real solutions to the problem, but rather workarounds that aren't guaranteed.

**Bottom line questions:**

1) Is this method of having a centralized message box hidden in the Master page a viable method of handling error/notifications messages?  Are there any other potential pitfalls that we just haven't noticed yet?

2) How can we handle the "Back" button dilemma?